# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML
>   file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.CardView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.hfad.bitsandpizzas-pFsCVGHBTBShhdbfE75xtw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.hfad.bitsandpizzas-pFsCVGHBTBShhdbfE75xtw==/lib/x86,
>   /system/lib]]
>           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>           at com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.data.NearbyGreetRecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NearbyGreetRecyclerViewAdapter.java:39)
>           at com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.data.NearbyGreetRecyclerViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NearbyGreetRecyclerViewAdapter.java:25)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6411)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5597)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5482)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5478)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2215)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1542)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1502)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3625)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3354)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3886)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1197)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1766)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131)
>           at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
>           at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1389)
>           at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:868)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
>   2018-11-03 20:17:21.037 7084-7084/com.hfad.bitsandpizzas
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:753)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2792)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2319)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

GreetFragment

```
package com.hfad.bitsandpizzas;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.Util.Constants;
import com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.Util.MapJSONToModel;
import com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.data.NearbyGreetRecyclerViewAdapter;
import com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.model.Gang;
import com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.model.Greet;
import com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.model.NearbyGreet;
import com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.model.User;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class GreetFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private NearbyGreetRecyclerViewAdapter nearbyGreetRecyclerViewAdapter;
    private List<NearbyGreet> nearbyGreets = new ArrayList<>();
    private RequestQueue queue;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_greets, container, false);

        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(inflater.getContext());

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(inflater.getContext()));

        nearbyGreets = getNearbyGreets();

        nearbyGreetRecyclerViewAdapter = new NearbyGreetRecyclerViewAdapter(inflater.getContext(), nearbyGreets);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(nearbyGreetRecyclerViewAdapter);
        nearbyGreetRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        return rootView;
    }

    //Get movies
    public List<NearbyGreet> getNearbyGreets() {
        nearbyGreets.clear();

        JsonArrayRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                Constants.URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject parent = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        JSONObject greetJSON = parent.getJSONObject("greet");
                        Greet greet = MapJSONToModel.mapJSONToGreet(greetJSON);

                        JSONObject userJSON = greetJSON.getJSONObject("user");
                        User user = MapJSONToModel.mapJSONToUser(userJSON);
                        greet.setUser(user);

                        if (greetJSON.has("gang") && !greetJSON.isNull("gang")) {
                            JSONObject gangJSON = greetJSON.getJSONObject("gang");
                            Gang gang = MapJSONToModel.mapJSONToGang(gangJSON);
                            greet.setGang(gang);
                        }

                        NearbyGreet nearbyGreet = new NearbyGreet();
                        nearbyGreet.setGreet(greet);
                        nearbyGreet.setDistance(BigDecimal.valueOf(parent.getDouble("distance")));

                        nearbyGreets.add(nearbyGreet);
                    }

                    nearbyGreetRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                params.put("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImF1dGgiOiJST0xFX0FETUlOLFJPTEVfVVNFUiIsImV4cCI6MTU0Mzg0ODExM30.Hj4b3kvZvg_XpRGqYGWrIfZVv3Cnt5kwHXG1YdSdhCga_BXuP_BLFAR3eLB1gU3q6-QLqTAuyrCAmEHSY3Fgiw");
                return params;
            }
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }
        };

        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

        return nearbyGreets;
    }
}
```

NearbyGreetRecyclerViewAdapter

```
package com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.data;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.R;
import com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.model.Greet;
import com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.model.NearbyGreet;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class NearbyGreetRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NearbyGreetRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private Context context;
    private List<NearbyGreet> nearbyGreets;

    public NearbyGreetRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<NearbyGreet> nearbyGreets) {
        this.context = context;
        this.nearbyGreets = nearbyGreets;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.greet_row, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view, context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        NearbyGreet nearbyGreet = nearbyGreets.get(position);

        holder.title.setText(nearbyGreet.getGreet().getTitle());
        Log.e("hehy", String.valueOf(nearbyGreets.size()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return nearbyGreets.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        TextView title;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView, final Context ctx) {
            super(itemView);
            context = ctx;

            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.greetTitleID);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                  //  Movie movie = movieList.get(getAdapterPosition());

                    //Intent intent = new Intent(context, MovieDetailActivity.class);

                    //intent.putExtra("movie", movie);
                    //ctx.startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you add `cardview-v7` dependency to your `build.gradle`.

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    // Other dependencies ...
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0"
}
```